# R - sorting nested list

Tags: r

I have nested list, for example:

```
x <- c(as.list(c("b", 4)), as.list(c("a", 4)))
```

Is it possible to order it by the second element in the sublists?

Comment: This gives a list of four elements. Do you mean `x <- list(as.list(c("b", 4)), as.list(c("a", 4)))`?

Comment: Your example is bad, but `purrr::sort_by` is good: `library(purrr) ; x <- list(list("b", 4), list("a", 3)) ; x %>% sort_by(2)` In base, `x[order(sapply(x, \`[[\`, 2))]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this as an example:

```
x <- c(list(c("b", 4)), list(c("a", 4)), list(c("b", 3)) )
```

And to order by the second element in each list you can use this:

```
> x[ order ( sapply(x, "[[", 2) )]
[[1]]
[1] "b" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "4"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "4"
```

The `saplly(... , "[[" , <n>)` paradigm is often useful for extracting from the results of `strsplit`:

```
> z <- strsplit(c( "test of sentence reading", "another test", "something esle") , split=" ")
> sapply(z, "[[", 2)
[1] "of"   "test" "esle"
```